# Trouble with resizing a players hitbox in a 2d java game

Tags: java, 2d, game-physics

So ,I'm attempting to run some simple checks on what keys are being pressed and based on that i'll change the size and shape of the player `hitbox (bounds.x,y,height,and width)`.

However it only responds to the one that test for all the keys not being pressed and when I remove that part of the program it uses the `default_creature` values.

```
public Player(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
    super(handler, x, y, Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH,
            Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT);

    if (handler.getKeyManager().left || handler.getKeyManager().right) {
        bounds.x = 0;
        bounds.y = 32;
        bounds.width = 60;
        bounds.height = 28;
    }
    if (!handler.getKeyManager().downtrue && !
            handler.getKeyManager().up && !handler.getKeyManager().left
            && !handler.getKeyManager().right) {
        bounds.x = 16;
        bounds.y = 32;
        bounds.width = 32;
        bounds.height = 28;
    }
    if (handler.getKeyManager().downtrue) {
        bounds.x = 0;
        bounds.y = 32;
        bounds.width = 60;
        bounds.height = 28;
    }
}
```

Comment: " however it only responds to the one that test for all the keys not being pressed and when I remove that part of the program it uses the deafault_creature values.": oh yeah now we understand

Comment: the part testing if no keys are being pressed (the second if statement ) is the only one working the others will not respond